# How to solve "FailedAuthenticationException: The Audience URI could not be validated."

Tags: sharepoint, azure, claims-based-identity, windows-live-id

I'm trying to set Windows Live ID identity provider on Azure Cloud, as a Trusted Identity Provider for Sharepoint 2013 instance. So far I created a new SPTRustedIdentityTokenIssuer on the farm, and added it to the Sharepoint application as a Trusted Identity Provider. However, after I select Windows Live ID as authentication method on the site, I get the Server Error in / Application, with the message I put in the title

> "FailedAuthenticationException: The Audience URI could not be
>   validated."

My url at this point is https://[myserver]/_trust, if that helps.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @mafalda have you? :)